# Spring Boot Context Path omitted when deployed to AWS Lambda

Tags: java, spring-boot, aws-lambda

We have a Spring Boot application that we're trying to migrate to AWS Lambda using the aws-serverless-java-container-springboot2 library. However, on Lambda, we see that the server.servlet.context-path we configure in our application.yml needs to be omitted from the request URI, for the request to be directed to the correct controller endpoint.

Is it possible to have Lambda recognize the context-path defined in application.yml and process the requests without having to omit the context-path when making requests?

We tried using dispatcherServlet to configure the endpoints, however it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: You don't talk to a Lambda on a URL really unless you have API gateway in front of it.  How are you accessing the Lambda?

Comment: We're using an ALB to talk to the Lambda.